# nltk data out of date

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I have installed NLTK on my machine... after that I am writing the following block of Python code...

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

After that a GUI opens which shows the packages/corpora that can be downloaded...
there are 3 headings respectively

```
all                  out of date
all-corpora          out of date 
book                 out of date
```

as a result i am unable to download from the book identifier... any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If downloading totally is unsuccessful, you could download manually. For details, if you fail in some parts, you could click "Refresh" button and choose which part you want to download again, then click "download" button.
Good luck!